# Django: AttributeError: class Meta has no attribute 'model'

Tags: django-rest-framework

Using  `Django 1.7.2` and `djangorestframework==3.0.2`

Getting error `AttributeError: class Meta has no attribute 'model'` for

```
class NotificationCountSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   ------
   ------

    class Meta:
        fields = ('drivers_count', 'vehicles_count', 'maps_count')
```

although same code working for  `Django==1.8` and `djangorestframework==3.2.3`

Is this the issue with django or djangorestframework version ?

Comment: Pass model attribute in the class Meta: model=Notification as follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your version of Django.

From the 1.8 changelog:

---

> What’s new in Django 1.8
>
> Model._meta API
>
> Django now has a formalized API for Model._meta, providing an
>   officially supported way to retrieve fields and filter fields based on
>   their attributes.
>
> The Model._meta object has been part of Django since the days of
>   pre-0.96 “Magic Removal” – it just wasn’t an official, stable API. In
>   recognition of this, we’ve endeavored to maintain
>   backwards-compatibility with the old API endpoint where possible.
>   However, API endpoints that aren’t part of the new official API have
>   been deprecated and will eventually be removed. A guide to migrating
>   from the old API to the new API has been provided