# How to read / write to elasticsearch using Django REST framework？

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I am trying to read / write to elasticsearch using Django REST framework.

As a result of investigation, I found the following method using Elasticsearch DSL.

[elasticsearch-with-django-the-easy-way](Https://medium.freecodecamp.com/elasticsearch-with-django-the-easy-way-909375bc16cb)

However, this method is written to the DB at the same time as elasticsearch.
How can I write this in only elasticsearch?

I'm sorry. My English is not very strong.

Comment: You should investigate the Haystack module which integrates ES with Django: https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find framework for `REST Django` and `elasticsearch` connection you can check this one : http://django-rest-elasticsearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html. And if you wanna to create `NoSQL` solution for guide which you found, you should create `Django` app without models and just indexed your `elasticsearch` data from `json` or `.tsv/.csv` file using `elasticsearch-dsl`. It will be something like :

```
class ElementIndex(DocType):
    ROWNAME = Text()
    ROWNAME = Text()

    class Meta:
        index = 'index_name'

def indexing(self):
    obj = ElementIndex(
        ROWNAME=str(self['NAME']),
        ROWNAME=str(self['NAME'])
    )
    obj.save(index="index_name")
    return obj.to_dict(include_meta=True)

def bulk_indexing(args):

    # ElementIndex.init(index="index_name")
    ElementIndex.init()
    es = Elasticsearch()

    //here your result dict with data from source

    r = bulk(client=es, actions=(indexing(c) for c in result))
    es.indices.refresh()
```

And as i said you can use `REST` with `elastic` from link above. Then create your `Django` templates or use `ReactJS` or something else to create frontend.

Comment: no need to call `obj.save(index="index_name")`, `bulk` will do it

Comment: By creating 'ElementIndex' , throws error 'AttributeError: type object 'Meta' has no attribute 'model'', can you please help?

Comment: @AALAPJETHWA Maybe Django version issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693512/django-attributeerror-class-meta-has-no-attribute-model